# Parameter to Oracle Package

Tags: plsql

I have an oracle package with a constant value at the top of PKB file as below

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY GEOHELPER AS

g_SRID pls_integer := 4326;
...
...
```

For some customers I want to user 4326 and for some 5638. What is the best method to change this value at compile/ release time from a .bat file? I do not want to have two versions of my package. Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at conditional compilation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-jul/o46plsql-096385.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/overview/plsql-conditional-compilation-133587.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment, conditional compilation is an option if you are using at least Oracle 10g R2.

In your script used for package recompilation, use the following ALTER to set specific conditional compilation flag which you can use later, during package compilation:

```
ALTER SESSION SET plsql_ccflags='variable_name:1';
```

Then, in the package body, use the conditional compilation IF statement:

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY GEOHELPER AS

$IF $$variable_name = 1
$THEN
  g_SRID pls_integer := 4326;
$ELSIF $$variable_name = 2
$THEN
  g_SRID pls_integer := 5232;
$ELSE
  g_SRID pls_integer := 0;
$END

...
```